# ASCII terminology and HTML

Tags: html, ascii

I have a question about ASCII code and HTML.

Most sites state what ASCII is but then mention things like HTML alternative or HTML code. Is this still ASCII?

Any way, my actual question is, is `&lt;` ASCII (if not, what 'language' is it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASCII is an encoding : it defines how the char you see are encoded in 0 & 1 (in fact in bytes). This problem is totally unrelated to how a browser displays the characters it decodes in a HTML file.

You can send to a browser a file containing the characters `&lt;` in any encoding, be it UTF-8, ASCII, or another one.

`&lt;` is a [character entity reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_entity_reference), coming from SGML and defined both in XML and HTML.

Here's [the official reference about HTML4 character entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html).

Comment: So, how 'language' is &lt; ?

Comment: `&lt;` is the word for `<` in the SGML language.

Comment: Even if the document is encoded in ascii, non-ascii characters are represented with entities-- or simply their numeric character code, in this case 60, by &#60;. Any Unicode character can be represented. See a ref here: http://amp-what.com

Answer (score 1):

`&lt;` is an HTML entity.  Html entities are used when a character cannot be safely used within the browser.  For example if you wanted to use a less than sign within the content of your page, using `<` would get interpreted by the browser as the start of a new tag.  Using an html entity tells the browser to render the actual character and not read it as the start of a tag.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Answer (score 1):

The notation `&lt;` consists of four characters, which all have a representation in the ASCII character code, but that’s immaterial. In HTML (as well as in SGML and XML), the notation denotes the LESS-THAN character “<”, in most contexts. The “<” character, too, has a representation in ASCII, but this too is immaterial.

People often use the expression “ASCII character” to denote a character that has a representation in ASCII, i.e. an ASCII code. In reality, the characters need not be ASCII encoded. But the concept “ASCII character” is still useful for some practical purposes. And using it, we can say that `&lt;` is a sequence of ASCII characters that denotes an ASCII character.

The “language” here is really a set of markup languages in which some sequences of ASCII characters are defined to mean certain (ASCII or non-ASCII) characters.

The need for using `&lt;` (when you wish to include “<” as text content) stems from the principle that in most contexts in HTML, the “<” character starts a tag, instead of being taken as such.

Things like `&lt;` are called *entity references* in SGML tradition, though in HTML contexts often prefixed with the word *character* to emphasize that the predefined entities of HTML all evaluate to single characters. The HTML5 drafts, abandoning the SGML tradition, use the term *named character references* instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Any way, my actual question is, is < ASCII (if not, what 'language'
>   is it)?

They are called entities and are part of HTML.